# mysql inner join makes server crash

Tags: php, mysql, database, inner-join

I have two tables, airports and runways.

```
airports:
id | ident | name              | latitude_deg | longitude_deg |
----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | KJFK  | JFK airport NYC   | 47.12345678  | 11.1234567    |
2  | KLAX  | Los Angeles Intl. | 20.12345678  | 9.12345678    |
...

runways:
id | airport_ident | le_ident | length
---------------------------------------
4  | KJFK          | 08/26    | 6000ft
5  | KJFK          | 20/02    | 3000ft
...
```

I am fetching all airports within the range of 70 miles with the following query (which works fine):

```
$output  = "SELECT distinct *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 47 ) ) * cos( radians( `airports`.latitude_deg ) ) * cos( radians( `airports`.longitude_deg ) - radians( 11 ) ) + sin( radians( 47 ) ) * sin( radians( `airports`.latitude_deg ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `airports` HAVING distance <= 70
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10";
```

How do I have to extend my query when I want to JOIN those two tables?
I have tried:

```
$output  = "SELECT distinct *, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( 47 ) ) * cos( radians( `airports`.latitude_deg ) ) * cos( radians( `airports`.longitude_deg ) - radians( 11 ) ) + sin( radians( 47 ) ) * sin( radians( `airports`.latitude_deg ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM `airports` INNER JOIN `runways` ON `airports`.ident = `runways`.airport_ident HAVING distance <= 70
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10";
```

but this crashes my server.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What crash error do you get from the server?

Comment: It doesn't respond! May be due to huge databases. I have to reboot the entire system every time.

Comment: Did you check the server's logs?

Comment: yes, no entries! - at least I don't have access.
How does the query look in your eyes?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that query is going to be as slow as molasses. It has to calculate the distance of every single possible combination of airports across your entire database in order to work out which ones have a distance of less then 70 before it then cuts the results down to ten entries to give you. It's going to absolutely thrash the database, and no amount of table indexing is going to help.

You're going to need to work out a way to avoid using the calculated distance field in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause.

Probably the most easiest way you could achieve this fairly easily is to cheat. Create a table that contains all the calculated distances between each airport, and query that. The distances aren't going to change, so it makes sense not to have to re-calculate them every time someone looks at your site.

You're going to need to do the calculations for every combination at some point, but you only have to do it once, and it doesn't have to be when the user is waiting for the page to load.

Yes, this approach will increase the amount of storage space your database requires, but the reward is that it will make your queries lightning fast.

If you want to make it even faster, it would also be helpful to limit the records being joined using the raw lat/long fields. If you want a radius of 70 miles, we know that neither lat nor long can be more than 70 miles difference from the source, so you can add those as filters; this means you can filter the query down to records within a 140x140 mile square before we even start looking at the actual calculated distance. This should drastically reduce the number of records your query has to search, and should speed things up even more, even with the pre-calculated distance table.

Comment: The `having` clause breaks things because the only way it can know if a given record has `distance <= 70` is to calculate it, so it has to calculate for every single possible record. It's always a bad idea to use a calculated field in a `having` or `where` clause for this reason. If it does work in the simple case, it'll be more by luck than anything else. I guess that the second query is slow because it's used up the servers RAM, and is moving into swap space. You might fix that by adding ram, but what happens when you have another user? Even if you get it working, it's not scalable.

Comment: Anyway, the suggesting in my final paragraph could be used even if you don't go with the idea of caching the calculations. Restrict the long and lat to a limited range as an additional set of `having` or `where` clauses, and it won't have to do nearly so much calculating to work out whether a record should be included because it would be able to ignore most records just by looking at the static long/lat values.